# Deploy entrypoint contract on an new op stack chain using safe-singleton-factory

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

Hello I wanna deploy the entrypoint contract to our op stack chain we have the testnet running tryna follow this [Safe developers documentation](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory#safe-developers-documentation) and I did submit a transaction to our testnet but what  want is how can I use it to deploy the entrypoint contract to our testnet with `safe-singleton-factory`

Answer (score 0):

If you followed this documentation and the transaction was successfully submitted, then this means that your singleton contract has been correctly deployed. The hash of the transaction should appear in the logs, and the address of the contract should appear in a block explorer when you enter that hash, under the `to` field.

Did that answer your question?

Best,
Louis